# Arcpy: Insert a text if filed is empty

Tags: arcpy, cursor, loop

I want to run a python code that, if 4 fields are empty, insert in the first of them a text. The fields are all designed to contain text. My code is:

```
import arcpy
import xlrd 
import numpy 
import pdb
arcpy.env.workspace = r"Directory"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
shape = r"C:\Directory\Shapefiles.shp"
fields = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shape,fields)
for row in cursor:
    if row[0] == None:
        if row[1]== None:
            if row[2]== None:
                if row[3]== None:
                    row[0] = 'Not_Officially_Recorded'
    cursor.updateRow(row)
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(shape, r'Anotherdirectory')
print('Done')
```

Anyway, the code runs suspiciously quickly and after I look at it, I see that nothing has been done. So what may the error be?

Comment: Are you sure they are "empty" or Null? Are you sure they don't contain empty strings ('')?

Comment: Actually they contained a " " string, that I had not idea how to notice. Now I replaced the correction criterion and it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be more efficient to use `and` with your `if` statements, or how I would do it would be to check if the length of the list of your row values is 0 using a filter (using `all` is another good option here).  This is how I would do it:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Directory"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
shape = r"C:\Directory\Shapefiles.shp"
fields = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shape,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if len(filter(None, row)) == 0:  
            row[0] = 'Not_Officially_Recorded'
            cursor.updateRow(row)

arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(shape, 'Anotherdirectory')
print('Done')
```

You also have a few modules you're importing that don't appear to be used...You also only need to use the raw string syntax for full paths, doing it for a simple string with no  special characters isn't necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just realized the issue was a little bit different, i.e. the feature was not actually empty but had a " " and that was the reason why it did not worked. Still your suggestions gave me a good way to make the code smoother and more elegant. Thank you. PS: the packages not reported here are used later in the code, that is the reason why they are there but I forgot to remove them while I posted the question.

Comment: Yeah, I have ran into that problem too where the field appears to be empty, but there is a `" "` value.  One way you can bypass that problem is to use something like `if len(filter(lambda x: str(x) not in ("", "None"), row)) == 0:`

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will keep it in mind for the next time I need to do it (probably quite soon). Thank you a lot

Comment: No problem, and I actually made a mistake, I forgot to add `.strip()` to that expression, so it should be: `if len(filter(lambda x: str(x).strip() not in ("", "None"), row)) == 0:`